# How to use file picker from command line

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, terminal, termux, intents

I would like to launch a file picker from a script to graphically select file. While I am able to launch a file picker by sending intent

```
am start -a android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT -d /storage/emulated/0 -t '*/*'
```

I can't see any way to get selection back to script. The command returns immediately and after file is chosen the dialog is simply closed.

Comment: I kind of doubt if it's possible to retrieve the paths from the Terminal because it's tightly linked to the Android app framework (the Intent on [`onActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)), but I may be wrong.

Comment: However, for [Termux specifically](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Internal_and_external_storage), looks like it has plugins to allow using file picker.

Comment: `am start` is an asynchronous command that means it always returns immediately and there is no way to get any return value from the intent/activity that has been started.

Comment: @AndrewT. Termux provides `termux-storage-get` script which calls functionality from [Termux:API](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/termux/api/apis/StorageGetAPI.java) but it's very limited. Only single file is allowed with no ability to specify MIME types. Perhaps it could be improved